# Adding footer on an iPhone app with SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to add a footer that will extend to the very bottom of the screen, and tried some methods I found on Google and ChatGPT but still no luck. I added  `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` but it doesn't seem to do anything either.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    // Yellow rectangle footer
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 16)
        .background(Color(red:1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17))
        
}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

[image: screenshot]

And also, is there a way to fix this footer in its position like using `position: fixed` on HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the yellow band is not extending into the safe area is because it is not touching it. You just need to add a `Spacer` to your `VStack` to push it down and it works.

While we're at it, you are using a couple of deprecated techniques in your example:

- `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` is deprecated, use a `GeometryReader` instead
- `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is deprecated, use `.ignoresSafeArea` instead.

In fact, you don't need to know the screen size. If you want a view to occupy the maximum possible width then use `maxWidth: .infinity` instead. The same goes for height. You don't even need `.ignoresSafeArea`, because you are using `background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)` which ignores safe areas by default.

Here is an updated version:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Spacer()

    // Yellow rectangle footer
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .frame(height: 16)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red:1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17))
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Using a `VStack` in this way is exactly how you can fix the footer to the bottom of the screen with SwiftUI. If the other content in the `VStack` might need more height then you can put a `ScrollView` around it. A `ScrollView` is greedy and occupies as much space as possible (just like a `Spacer`). So then the example would look like this:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    ScrollView {
        // Your main content here
    }
    // Yellow rectangle footer
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .frame(height: 16)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red:1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17))
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I haven't done it yet, but when I add contents in the middle, would the footer hold its position? (sticky footer?)

Comment: Yes, provided the content inside the ```VStack``` does not need so much space that there there is not enough height to display it all. But using a ```ScrollView``` solves this, the footer will always be at the bottom.

Comment: @mybraincellssayhi, If this answer resolves your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add something like a fixed position. In SwiftUI, everything was aligned. So in this case, simply add a `Space` above `Rectangle` like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
            
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 16)
            .background(Color(red:1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17))
    }
}
```

[image]